# Столкнулся с проблемой , при попытки записи с файла появляется ошибка LNK2019. Не могу понять в чем проблема

Tags: c

Ошибка `LNK2019` ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ `_fscnaf` в функции `_main`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

typedef struct Node {
            char* name;
            int quanity;
            int buy;
            int sell;
            struct Node *next;
        }Node;

        void printFromHead(const Node* list);

        int main(){
            Node *head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            char name [200] = "D:/start.txt";

        FILE *S1;
            S1 = fopen(name,"r");
            fscanf(S1, "%s", head->name);
            fscanf(S1, "%d", &head->quanity);
            fscanf(S1, "%d", &head->buy);
            fscnaf(S1, "%d", &head->sell);
            fclose(S1);
            printFromHead(head);
            free(head);
            return 0; 
        }
```

Comment: `fscanf(S1, "%s", head->name);` - куда попадает текст?

Comment: В односвязный список , выше приведен фрагмент кода

Comment: не вижу распределения памяти для `head->name`

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?? Выделение динамической памяти для char* name??

Comment: ну хорошо, хотите - назовите это так

Comment: Я немного не понимаю как это сделать , можете помочь (как это должно выглядеть в коде)?

Comment: `LNK2019` для **каких символов**? Почему в вопросе отсутствует полный текст ошибки? Тот код, который вы тут привели, разумеется не будет компилироваться, ибо ни объявления, ни определения некоей функции `printFromHead` в нем не приведено. Что такое `printFromHead`?

Comment: у меня есть прототип функции printFromHead ( он находиться в Header-файле , я забыл его указать тут )

Comment: Так а какой смысл тогда ожидать какого-то объяснения LNK2019, если вы привели лишь какой-то огрызок кода? Еще раз: LNK2019 для каких символов вы получаете?

Comment: @AnT Потому что ТС верит в нас (в Вас).

Comment: Это почти весь код ( без описания функции printFromHead). Данная ошибка появилась после того , как я попытался записать данные из файла.

Comment: Еще раз: **LNK2019 для каких символов вы получаете?** Где полный текст сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: @AnT Я не понимаю суть этой ошибки и о каких символах идёт речь. Можете объяснить что имеется ввиду  когда вы говорите символы

Comment: Полный текст сообщения LNK2019 будет содержать имя переменной или функции, которые линкер не смог найти. Вот это и есть "символы", о которых я веду речь.

Comment: Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _fscnaf в функции _main. Это все что там написано

Comment: И? Неужели было так трудно сразу процитировать полный текст сообщения? И вам не очевидно в чем проблема уже из этого сообщения об ошибке? Или это совсем не ваш код и вы в нем "ни бум бум"?

Comment: Да нет , код  мой , просто невнимательный , спасибо вам)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде в одном из случаев написано `fscnaf` вместо `fscanf`. Компилятор, без сомнения указал вам на эту ошибку во время компиляции. А затем еще и линкер сообщил через LNK2019.

Находить детские опечатки в своем коде вы должны уметь без помощи Интернета.